# Prove that $\|\mathbf{L}\|_{op}$=$\underset{\mathbf{w}∈\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbf{w}\neq0}{\operatorname{sup}}$ $\frac{\|\mathbf{Lw}\|}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let **L** $: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear function.

Prove that $\|$**L**$\|_{op}$=$\underset{\mathbf{w}∈\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbf{w}\neq0}{\operatorname{sup}}$ $\frac{\|\mathbf{Lw}\|}{\|\mathbf{w}\|}$

I'm really not too sure on this question and have been stuck on it for a while so any help will be appreciated.

The definition in the course is 
$$ \| \mathbf{L} \|_{op} = \sup_{\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{R}^d, \|\mathbf{u}\| \leq 1\} \| \mathbf{L}u \| $$

Comment: What is $\|\cdot\|_{\textrm{op}}$? Is it the operator norm associated with $\|\cdot\|$? If so, what is your definition of $\|\cdot\|_{\textrm{op}}$?

Comment: What you wrote is usually the definition of the operator norm. So, if you are using another definition, you should state so.

Comment: Our definition is:  $||\mathbf{L}||_{op}$=$\underset{\mathbf{u}∈\mathbb{R}^d,||\mathbf{u}||≤1}{\operatorname{sup}}$||$\mathbf{Lu}$|| @C.Falcon

Comment: @MartinArgerami

Comment: And it is the operator norm @C.Falcon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $E$ denotes any normed vector space.

Note that, if $u \in E$ and $u \neq 0$, by the properties of the norm: 
 $$ \frac{\| Lu \|}{\| u \|}=\| u \|^{-1} \| Lu \| = \| L ( u \| u \|^{-1} ) \|$$
and $ \| \ u \| u \|^{-1} \ \|=1$, this essentially shows that

$$ \sup_{x \in E, x \neq 0} \frac{\| Lu \|}{\| u \|}=\sup_{x \in E, \| x \|=1} \| L u \| $$

Then you are left to prove that:

$$ \sup_{x \in E, \| x \|=1} \| L u \|=\sup_{x \in E, \| x \|\le1} \| L u \|, $$

which is not difficult.

Since $\{ x \in E : \| x \| = 1 \} \subset \{ x \in E : \| x \| \le 1 \}$, it suffices to prove that $l=\sup_{x \in E, \| x \|\le1} \| L x \| \le \sup_{x \in E, \| x \|=1} \| L x \|$. Fix any $\epsilon > 0 $, by the definition of least upper bound, there exists $ x_0 \in E$ such that $x_0 \neq 0$, $\| x_0 \| \le 1 $ and

$$ |l-\epsilon| \le \| Lx_0 \| \underbrace{\le}_{\| x_0 \| \le 1} \frac{\| Lx_0 \|}{\| x_0 \|} = \| L(x_0 \|x_0 \|^{-1}) \| \le \sup_{x \in E, \|x\|=1} \| L x \|  $$

The claim follows since $\epsilon $ was arbitrary.

Comment: Sorry for being a nuisance, but how would you go by proving your last statement, I've been trying for the last hour with no luck.

Comment: Editing as soon as possible :)

Comment: @carpul790 see his latest edit